# Running a BroadcastReceiver continuously in the background to monitor network status..

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-location, android-networking

i am writing an android application to continuously monitor the network in the background after every minute... i am using a BroadcastReceiver... it starts when the boot is completed.... and inside the BroadcastReceiver i am doing following things

```
       a. Monitor Network
       b. check signal strength
       c. fetch longitude and latitude
       d. fetch phonenumber 
       e. fetch operatorname

     and i am saving all the above information into a Database table....
```

but unfortunately this application is giving me some errors when i install and run it on android device

my BroadcastReceiver code is :-

```
public class NetworkInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private NetworkInfoVO networkInfoVO = new NetworkInfoVO();
    private String strNetworkInfo = QualityofServiceConstants.DEFAULT_NETWORK_INFO;
    private SignalStrengthPhoneStateListner signalStrengthPhoneStateListner =  new SignalStrengthPhoneStateListner();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                //Check Network status here
        if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            String networkState = getNetworkStateString(networkInfo.getState());
            String stateString = networkInfo.toString().replace(',', '\n');
            strNetworkInfo = String.format("Network Type: %s\n Network State: %s\n\n %s",
            networkInfo.getTypeName(),networkState,stateString);
        }

                //check signal strength here
        telephonyManager.listen(signalStrengthPhoneStateListner, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        networkInfoVO.setNetworkInfo(strNetworkInfo);
                //get phonenumber here
        networkInfoVO.setPhoneNumber(telephonyManager.getLine1Number());
                //get operator name here
        networkInfoVO.setServiceProvider(telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName());
//get signal strength here      networkInfoVO.setSignalStrength(signalStrengthPhoneStateListner.getSignalStrengths());
                //get latitude here
        networkInfoVO.setLatitude(String.valueOf(getGPS(context).getLatitude()));
                //get longitude here
        networkInfoVO.setLongitude(String.valueOf(getGPS(context).getLongitude()));
        networkInfoVO.setTime(new Date().toString());

        new NetworkInfoDatabaseHelper(context).saveRecord(networkInfoVO);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private String getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State state){

        String stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_UNKNOWN;

        switch(state)
        {
        case CONNECTED: 
            stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED;             
            break;

        case CONNECTING:        
            stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTING;    
            break;

        case DISCONNECTED:      
            stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISCONNECTED;  
            break;

        case DISCONNECTING:     
            stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISCONNECTING;  
            break;

        case SUSPENDED:         
            stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_SUSPENDED;              
            break;

        default: 
            stateString = QualityofServiceConstants.NETWORK_STATE_UNKNOWN;     

            break;

        }

        return stateString;
    }


    private Location getGPS(Context context){

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String>providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location location = null;

        for (int i = providers.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            if(location!=null)
                break;
        }

        return location;
    }

    private class SignalStrengthPhoneStateListner extends PhoneStateListener{

        private String signalStrengths;

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

            if(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() > 30){
                signalStrengths = "Signal Strength :" + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() + " Good";
            }else if(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() > 20 && signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() < 30){
                signalStrengths = "Signal Strength : " + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() + " Average";
            }else if(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() < 20){
                signalStrengths = "Signal Strength : " + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() + " Weak";
            }

        }

        public String getSignalStrengths() {
            return signalStrengths;
        }

    }

}
```

my manifest file is :-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="compervazive.lognetworkinfo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.example.qos.broadcastreceiver.NetworkInfoReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIG_STR"/>                                                                                                                                     
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please let me know what is the problem in this.... Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: You want us to guess what the errors are or what?

Comment: application is not getting installed... i want you to please look at the manifest file... and let me know if all the permissions and intent filters are correct...

Comment: Does it give a reason why it's not installed?

Comment: What do you mean by `application not getting installed`? Do you see any error when installing the app or it does not show up in the Launcher? The reason why it does not show up in the launcher is because you do not have any launcher activity n your manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Thread.sleep(60000);
```

This is very bad idea, remove this and reread BroadcastReceiver's documentation. Maybe it will help.

Also you do not have any activity in your manifest. Add at least one main launcher activity. Any app must have at least one.

P.S. give us more info about errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED
```

should probably be

```
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```